# Do you need any specific tools to change a DPF and vaporizer?

Tags: ford, diesel-particulate-filter, mondeo, mk4

I've just been charged a ridiculous amount for a new vaporizer and a DPF clean. I could have bought an entirely new DPF and vaporizer myself and fitted them at home for less than what I just paid.

Is there anything to be aware of if I were to do this in future? Would I need any specific tools to prime the system after replacement or will the car handle everything for me when it next tries a regeneration? I would assume that since I would be replacing both parts it would just be a case of swapping the parts and everything would be fine.

Comment: The main issue is that some makes need to reset their cleaning cycles. I don't know if thats true in your case. The rest ought to be straightforward and needs only a generic toolset.
I had some bad experience working on the DPF: They are made of stainless steel, I had heavy fretting on the pressure sensor takeoff fitting, almost making it necessary to weld it.